# Indigo Target Platform missing javax.xml

Tags: java, osgi, eclipselink, eclipse-indigo, target-platform

I'm using Eclipse *Indigo* and have problems with the setup of an indigo RCP target platform.
The Platform consists of the 'EclipseLink' and the 'Eclipse RCP SDK' libraries. I have used the update site to select the bundles.
Now, when I look to the "Target Platform State-View" it tells me:

```
Missing Constraint: Import-Package: javax.xml; version=[1.3.0,2.0.0)
```

When I start an RCP sample it tells me the same (with "Validate Plugins prior to startup" enabled) throws an exception during startup, but starts.
Do you know the reason of this error, or why I cant find this plugin anywhere?

PS: The plugin *javax.xml.stream* is missing javax.xml
Regards Markus

Answer (score 4):

Most of the javax.* packages are not available by default. I ususally use the Eclipse Orbit repositories to pull them in:

http://www.eclipse.org/orbit/

They provide an update site/p2 repository where the javax packages can be found.

Comment: I added http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20120119162704/repository to my target definition, and you could then select JAXP XML 1.3.4... to be included.